# Electron dialog.showOpenDialog() returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, dialog } = require('electron');

const fs = require('fs');

const path = require('path')

let mainWindow = null;

app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ show: false, webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true } });

    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
    mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        mainWindow.show();
        //mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

        getFileFromUser();
    });

    mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
        mainWindow = null;
    });
});

const getFileFromUser = async () => {
    // Triggers the OS' Open File Dialog box. We also pass it as a Javascript
    // object of different configuration arguments to the function

    const files = await dialog.showOpenDialog(mainWindow, {
        // The Configuration object sets different properties on the Open File Dialog 
        properties: ['openFile']
    }).catch((err)=> {
        return callback(err)
    })

    if (!files) {
        return;
    }

    const file = files[0];
    const content = fs.readFileSync(file).toString();
    console.log(content)
}
```

Comment: This is the error message I am getting

Comment: (node:4268) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type undefined
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:439:10)
    at Object.func (electron/js2c/asar.js:140:31)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140:31)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:349:35)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542:40)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542:40)
    at getFileFromUser

Comment: (C:\Users\Nemi\electronPractice\noteeditor\app\main.js:72:24)
(node:4268) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:4268) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

Comment: When I try to console.log file after extracting from files[0], it gives me 'undefined'. I think there is a problem in the way the element is extracted from the files array

Comment: When I loop over the array and console.log(files[i]), there is no content to be printed

Comment: Put a then after the catch, .then((err) => { console.log(err) }) and the error went away, but the file content is still not being retrieved

Comment: please edit those comments into your question

Comment: second, state what electron version you're using

Comment: I'm using Electron 7.1.4